# How can I make Photo Slider by Chakra UI and Next.js?

Tags: next.js, chakra-ui

I use Next.js and Chakra UI for CSS.
How can I change the following GirdItem to Photo Slider?

The current UI is this

[image]

but I want to make like this

[image]
Is it possible to make it?

```
                <AspectRatio ratio={4 / 3} flex="0 0 auto" minWidth="100%">
                  <GridItem
                    cursor="pointer"
                    h="100%"
                    w="100%"
                    backgroundColor={alias.background.gray}
                    display="flex"
                    alignItems="center"
                    justifyContent="center"
                    onClick={() => {
                      inputRef.current?.click();
                    }}
                  >
                    <PlusIcon width={24} height={24} />
                    <UploadImage
                      ref={inputRef}
                      setImageUrls={updateImageUrls}
                      setImageFiles={updateImageFiles}
                    />
                  </GridItem>
                </AspectRatio>
```